# How to find a point on the wall as a center point of a clock?

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, coordinates

I create a cube as room and set camera inside it. I want to draw a clock on one of the walls. but when I draw a circle for showing clock, it doesn't work correctly. can anyone help me to draw a clock on the wall? here is my codes:

```
 void room(){
    if(flag){
        glRotatef(rt,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    }
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0 ,1.0);  //roof
    glNormal3f(0,-1,0);
    glVertex3f( 3.0, 3.0,-3.0); 
    glVertex3f(-3.0, 3.0,-3.0); 
    glVertex3f(-3.0, 3.0, 3.0); 
    glVertex3f( 3.0, 3.0, 3.0);

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0 ,0.0);  //floor
    glNormal3f(0,1,0);
    glVertex3f( 3.0,-3.0, 3.0); 
    glVertex3f(-3.0,-3.0, 3.0); 
    glVertex3f(-3.0,-3.0,-3.0); 
    glVertex3f( 3.0,-3.0,-3.0); 

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0 ,0.0); //behind wall
    glNormal3f(0,0,-1);
    glVertex3f( 3.0, 3.0, 3.0);  
    glVertex3f(-3.0, 3.0, 3.0);  
    glVertex3f(-3.0,-3.0, 3.0);  
    glVertex3f( 3.0,-3.0, 3.0);  

    glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0,1.0);   // front wall
    glNormal3f(0,0,1);
    glVertex3f( 3.0,-3.0,-3.0); 
    glVertex3f(-3.0,-3.0,-3.0); 
    glVertex3f(-3.0, 3.0,-3.0);  
    glVertex3f( 3.0, 3.0,-3.0); 

    glColor3f(0.0 ,0.0,1.0);  //left wall 
    glNormal3f(1,0,0);
    glVertex3f(-3.0, 3.0, 3.0); 
    glVertex3f(-3.0, 3.0,-3.0); 
    glVertex3f(-3.0,-3.0,-3.0); 
    glVertex3f(-3.0,-3.0, 3.0); 

    glColor3f( 0.2, 0.4, 0.0); // right wall
    glNormal3f(-1,0,0);
    glVertex3f( 3.0, 3.0,-3.0);  
    glVertex3f( 3.0, 3.0, 3.0);  
    glVertex3f( 3.0,-3.0, 3.0); 
    glVertex3f( 3.0,-3.0,-3.0);
}
void drawClock() {
    char buff[100];
    GLfloat x1=2.0;
    GLfloat y1=2.0;
    GLfloat z1=-3.0;
    GLfloat radius = 1.0;  // Radius 
    int angle;

    glLoadIdentity();
    //glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glOrtho(0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 20.0, -10.0, 10.0);

    // Draw circle
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(3.0,3.0,-3.0);    
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor3f(0.5,1.0,0.0);     
    glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);
    for(angle=0; angle <= 360; angle +=1)    
        glVertex3f(x1 + cos(angle * PI/180.0f)* radius, y1 + sin(angle *PI/180.0f)* radius, z1);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Judging by your commented lines, it appears you are applying these transformations to your projection matrix. While this can sometimes produce the correct results, you really should be using `ModelView` for this - GL gives you a ***much*** deeper stack for ModelView (32 levels minimum) vs. (2 minimum for Projection).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: what do I do exactly? please help me ! :(

Comment: `glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)` would take care of the issue I was discussing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center of the wall should be `(0, 0, -3)` not `(2, 2, -3)`. Probably it's better to use however `(0, 0, -2.9)` so that the clock is slightly inside and not exactly on the wall.

Also I'd say that you need to add

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
```

at the start of `room` function and

```
glEnd();
```

at the end of it.

Also why are you calling `glTranslatef` before drawing the clock if it uses the same coordinate system as the walls?

Comment: Now an invalid shape is drawn, that wasn't drawn anything. but yet it doesn't work correctly. :(

Comment: How can I draw a circle on the wall exactly?